# determine how many points one can travel given obstacles

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search, path-finding

Suppose we have a field with coordinates, and the robot start from `(0, 0)`, and can move up, down, left or right, but not diagonally.

For any given position `(x, y)`, the robot can move to `(x-1, y), (x+1, y), (x, y-1), (x, y+1)`, but not `(x-1, y-1), (x+1, y+1), (x-1, y+1), (x+1, y-1)`.

In addition, there are obstacles placed in a way that any location whose coordinates' digits add up to 21 or more, e.g. `(45, -94)` is an obstacle point because `4 + 5 + 9 + 4 = 22 >= 21`, but `(-112, 223)` is not because `1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 3 = 11 < 21`.
The robot cannot step into an obstacle or through it. It must move around it.

To determine the number of locations the robot can make, the first thought would be an exhaustive search with a breadth-first search.
- Is it the only way?
- Is there a faster way to do it?
- How can the knowledge of where obstacles are be used to solve it?

Comment: How fast is fast enough? A most straightforward, unoptimised brute force solution shouldn't take more than a few seconds on any reasonable PC. More like 0.1s with some minimal obvious improvements.

Comment: "an exhaustive search with a breadth-first search": this sounds contradictory. Can you explain ?

Comment: Unless the domains is bounded, there must be an infinity of locations.

Comment: but it is bounded, since all coordinates `(|x|, |y|) >= (1...(21 times)...1, 1...(21 times)...1)` are unreachable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A point is an obstacle if either x or y = +/- 399, so there is a complete rectangle of obstacle points from (-399,-399) to (399,399).

Since you can't reach anything outside that rectangle, there are fewer than 640000 reachable points, and a simple BFS is probably a reasonable solution.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the answer. My first thought was that this was not bounded so I'd like to know a faster approach. But I was wrong and it is bounded, it turns out it didn't take more than a second to do a bfs to get the answer.